# How many table are stored data in camunda database when creating new BPMN proc

Tags: database, bpmn, camunda

I have to create a BPMN process based on the Camunda BPM platform. But when the process is created successfully, I don't know how many tables stored data of top of the BPMN process. Could you show me the tables which are containing data of my BPMN process?

References: [Camunda Database Schema](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/database/#entity-relationship-diagrams)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a [Camunda forum discussion](https://forum.camunda.org/t/does-camunda-store-processes-definitions-in-the-database/1264), the

> process engine stores the XML in the database

Digging further leads to [another discussion entry](https://forum.camunda.org/t/how-to-access-task-properties-where-are-they-stored/1555/3)  which indicates that the XML is probably stored as one piece in the database:

> `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY` is correct. For correctly interpreting the `BYTES_` field, your report script must be able to detect the encoding from the XML declaration or assume one (should be UTF-8)

[image: Part of Camunda DB diagram]

This assumption is confirmed by [yet another forum entry](https://forum.camunda.org/t/how-to-get-files-form-camunda-mysql-database/2981) which says

> Usually files are getting stored as Blob in `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY`
>   (And as you have already mentioned, camunda saves the reference in `ACT_RU_VARIABLE.BYTEARRAY_ID_`)

There is also [documentation how to extract the information from the blobs](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.4/user-guide/process-engine/variables/#file-values).

Last but not least, according to [Camunda Userguide 7.5](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/database/), the process is also stored as machine readable format:

> The `ACT_RE_PROCDEF` table contains all deployed process definitions. It includes information like the version details, the resource name or the suspension state.